# What is the cleanest way to join in one array the result of two or more calls to Get-ChildItem?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm facing the problem of moving and copying some items on the file system with PowerShell.

I know by experiments the fact that, even with PowerShell v3, the cmdlet `Copy-Item`, `Move-Item` and `Delete-Item` **cannot handle correctly reparse point** like junction and symbolic link, and can lead to disasters if used with switch `-Recurse`.

I want to prevent this evenience. I have to handle two or more folder each run, so I was thinking to something like this.

```
$Strings = @{ ... }
$ori = Get-ChildItem $OriginPath -Recurse
$dri = Get-ChildItem $DestinationPath -Recurse

$items = ($ori + $dri) | where { $_.Attributes -match 'ReparsePoint' }
if ($items.Length -gt 0)
{
    Write-Verbose ($Strings.LogExistingReparsePoint -f $items.Length)
    $items | foreach { Write-Verbose "    $($_.FullName)" }
    throw ($Strings.ErrorExistingReparsePoint -f $items.Length)
}
```

This doen't work because `$ori` and `$dri` can be also single items and not arrays: the `op-Addition` will fail. Changing to

```
$items = @(@($ori) + @($dri)) | where { $_.Attributes -match 'ReparsePoint' }
```

poses another problem because `$ori` and `$dri` can also be `$null` and I can end with an array containing `$null`. When piping the join resutl to `Where-Object`, again, I can end with a `$null`, a single item, or an array.

The only apparently working solution is the more complex code following

```
$items = $()
if ($ori -ne $null) { $items += @($ori) }
if ($dri -ne $null) { $items += @($dri) }
$items = $items | where { $_.Attributes -match 'ReparsePoint' }

if ($items -ne $null)
{
    Write-Verbose ($Strings.LogExistingReparsePoint -f @($items).Length)
    $items | foreach { Write-Verbose "    $($_.FullName)" }
    throw ($Strings.ErrorExistingReparsePoint -f @($items).Length)
}
```

There is some better approch?

I'm interested for sure if there is a way to handle reparse point with PowerShell cmdlets in the correct way, but **I'm much more interested to know how to join and filters two or more "PowerShell collections"**.

I conclude observing that, at present, this feature of PowerShell, the "polymorphic array", doen't appear such a benefit to me.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: dir (aka Get-ChildItem) for the filesystem has -Attributes param.  `dir -Recurse -File -Attributes !ReparsePoint`.  Another trick is to always start with empty array if you want to finish with an list or array: `$items = @() + $ori + $dri # array concat, not math`.  PS3 MSDN: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847897(v=wps.620).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just add a filter to throw out nulls.  You're on the right track.

`$items = @(@($ori) + @($dri)) | ? { $_ -ne $null }`

Answer (score 0):

I've been on Powershell 3 for a while now but from what I can tell this should work in 2.0 as well:

```
$items = @($ori, $dri) | %{ $_ } | ? { $_.Attributes -match 'ReparsePoint' }
```

Basically `%{ $_ }` is a foreach loop that unrolls the inner arrays by iterating over them and passing each inner element (`$_`) down the pipeline. Nulls will automatically be excluded from the pipeline.